# installation of compiler gfortran in centos 6

Tags: gcc, centos, centos6, gfortran

I try to install some compilers. I use Centos 6 in my laptop. I have installed the gcc, the "GNU" C Compiler. I need to install also gfortran, but when I type `yum install gfortran`, I get the message `no package gfortran available`.

Do you know how can I install the fortran compiler?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `yum install gcc-gfortran`

You can use `yum search gfortran`, to view relevant packages

Comment: Now, I have it installed. Thanks