# Installing R 3.3.2 in RHEL 6.8 without yum

Tags: r, gcc, fortran, yum, rhel6

My goal is to install R 3.3.2 in RHEL 6.8 without yum inside an isolated system with no Internet access. I can only move source code to this sytem compile, build and run.

So when I:

```
.configure
```

the R source I get an error:

```
configure: error: No F77 compiler found
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720430/error-running-r-in-linux) but now I'm confused. I am under the impression that gcc 4.0 already has Fortran? I checked that:

```
gcc --version
```

Returns version 4.4.7.

Comment: There's some package you need to install from yum. I don't remember which offhand but I know that I use 3.3.2 on RHEL 6 with no problems and I didn't really go to great lengths to do it.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli Nope, gfortran is a part of GCC since version 4.0. Version 3 contained g77 Fortran compiler.

Comment: Hi @VadimirF this question is not a duplicate. The other question installs gfortran from yum. I cannot use yum since I do not have Internet access.

Comment: The point is you need that package. Just download it, copy it to your computer on a floppy disk or USB or whatever and install by `rpm -i` or even yum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC does come with a Fortran compiler - `gfortran`, but the Fortran part is often moved to a different package which is not installed by default. This is distribution specific.

In RHEL this package should be called `gcc-gfortran`. RHEL notoriously ships very old versions of GCC but R should be compatible with them anyway. See [installation of compiler gfortran in centos 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489208/installation-of-compiler-gfortran-in-centos-6)

You should have access to the RHEL `rpm` repositories included in your RHEL subscription. You should also be able to use the CentOS binary http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/gcc-gfortran-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64.rpm from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/

Just download the rpm file, copy it to your computer on a floppy disk or USB or whatever and install by `rpm -i` or `yum`. It is trivial and yum does work even in computers without internet access. Just download the rpm and copy it there.

Of course, you can always install a complete new version of GCC, be it from an rpm binaries or from sources from https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html Just follow the instructions in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir! I will give this a try and keep you posted.

Comment: Still no go :( 

I downloaded http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/gcc-gfortran-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64.rpm and installed via rpm -i and now I get another dependency failure:

error: Failed dependencies:
 libgfortran = 4.4.7-17.el6 is needed by gcc-gfortran-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64
 libgfortran.so.3()(64bit) is needed by gcc-gfortran-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64

Comment: Yes, install that one too.