# unable to install R on RedHat Linux

Tags: r, fortran

I am trying to install R from source code for RedHat Linux. when I execute

```
  ./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no
```

I get this error:

```
checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... none
checking for Fortran 77 name-mangling scheme... configure: error: in `/software/R/R-3.5.1':
configure: error: cannot compile a simple Fortran program
```

When can I get gfortran library? Is there an R distribution where all of the required libraries are bundled?

Comment: See if you already have `f77` and `gfortran`. http://tinyheero.github.io/2016/01/13/configure-r-cannot-compile-fortran.html

Comment: gfortran is not there. How can I download this and install?

Comment: If you can't use `yum` due to no network connection, grab the `rpm` and [install it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295807/installing-r-3-3-2-in-rhel-6-8-without-yum) If you don't have admin permissions, you'll have to get an admin account to install what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to install R, the easiest solution is to follow the [README on CRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/redhat/README):

- enable [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)
- `sudo yum install R`

If you have to compile it yourself, enabling EPEL still makes sense, since you can then use

```
sudo yum-builddep R
```

to install all the build dependencies of the EPEL build of R.

Comment: @user1471980 Then ask your sys-admin to do it for you. It might be possible to install a Fortran compiler in your `$HOME`, but if I were your sys-admin, I would prefer a system wide installation that is under my control.